# How do I get ping time in Powershell when using Test-Connection?

Tags: powershell, ping

I am new to PS scripting. I am in need of help with my code.
purpose:

1. Ping to get 4 times response in 15s, if fail to get 4 times response
   then ping every 1s until get 15 response, then back to 15s ping
2. Every ping need to create a file with the ping time

Here are my codes:

```
$ip = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

foreach($i in 1..10){
    $success = Test-Connection -Ping -IPV4 -Count 4 -TimeoutSeconds 15 -TargetName $ip -Quiet
    if ($success){
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Success"
    }
    else{
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "UnSuccess"
        do{
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Blue "Try Again"
            $success2 = Test-Connection -Ping -IPV4 -Count 15 -TimeoutSeconds 1 -TargetName $ip -Quiet
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "UnSuccess"
        }while ($success2 -eq $false)
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Try Success"
    }
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Blue "Sleep 15s"
    Start-Sleep -s 15
}
```

Comment: if you pipe $success2 to Get-Member you'll see `ResponseTime` So `$Success2.ResponseTime` will show you in ms how long it took

Comment: can you demo the code? because im unable to see the responseTime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(Test-Connection -IPv4 '12.0.0.1').ForEach{[PSCustomObject]@{Status = $_.Status; Latency = $_.Latency}} |
   Group-Object -Property Status |
      ForEach-Object {
         [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name = $_.Name
            avg = ($_.Group.Latency | Measure-Object -Average).Average
         }
      }
```

Comment: If i do like this, how do i get the return boolean from test-connection?